# Measuring Rotary Encoder Signal with Multimeter

Tags: encoder, pullup

I'd like to measure the A and B signal of an encoder (https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B079H3C98M/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o06_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) using my multimeter.

I've tried testing the A channel (CLK) by connecting one lead to the CLK output, and the other to GND. As I turn the encoder, the signal always remains at 5V. Can anyone explain why this is?

Note:

I've connected the encoder to an mbed, and although the results are not perfect, the mbed does seem to detect a change in pulse, which makes the matter even more confusing.

Comment: Since the encoder is a simple switch contact you can measure with a multimeter ...however only if the encoder is connected in a circuit with 5V supplied and measure voltage on the CLK/DT signals. http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-sensors-and-input/keyes-ky-040-arduino-rotary-encoder-user-manual/

Answer (score 1):

Because that encoder is not a plain encoder, it's a module with a serial interface. It sends a serial stream to the Arduino. You can't see a serial stream with a meter. You need a scope.

If you want to see the voltage change as you turn the shaft, measure directly on the pins of the encoder itself: the 3 pins away from the connector.

Answer (score 0):

The encoders like that one usually have contacts switching between the detents. The momentary connection change is hard to detect when you rotating it by hand. Try pinching shaft hard and rotate as slow as possible, you'd see the pulse.

Comment: Shouldn't one turn be enough to flip the state? I don't see why the channel would change state twice in one turn.

Comment: @B4039 The Ky-040 provides 20 positions per rotation ….so 10 pulses on CLK and DT

Answer (score 0):

Take a 5 volt supply, and connect - to the GND pin, and the + supply to the +5V pin.

Now, set up the multimeter to read volts (nominally 5). Connect the - lead to the GND pin, and the +IN to either CLK or DT. Now when you rotate the shaft, you should see the voltage switch from 0 to 5 volts and back.

Comment: It's not a pot. It's an encoder.

Comment: @DavideAndrea - Oops. You're right. However, what I meant to say was "shaft". I'll fix it. Thanks.